# Spring: FileNotFoundException when calling new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext()

Tags: java, spring

I am having this problem as described in subject.
I printed the working directory to be sure where do I run. 
I've tried the following code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
                System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        //load the spring configuration file
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        ...
}
```

and put the xml in the project root directory and in target directory for the first and second attempt above, and in the src directory for the second and third attempt (even when I didn;t think it is the correct place but all that currently was left for me is to shoot in any direction).

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at ttt.springdemo.HelloSpringApp.main(HelloSpringApp.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 13 more
```

[image: Project Structure]

This is the manifest.mf file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: TalT
Class-Path: lib/spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-jcl-5.0.8.REL
 EASE.jar lib/spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-aop-3.0.2.RE
 LEASE.jar lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar lib/spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar 
 lib/spring-expression-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-asm-3.0.2.RELEASE.
 jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.4
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_171
Main-Class: ttt.springdemo.HelloSpringApp
```

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your app structure tree ?

Comment: @georgesvan done

Comment: your applicationContext.xml should be at same classpath level as the (for instance ) the .dea file and src folder. It appears yours in located in the main folder

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty explicit: The file `applicationContext.xml` is not found. It means it is not existing or it is not at the correct location.

Possibilities:

- The file is not existing
- You're on a case sensitive file system (usually on linux / unix / macOS) and you did not use the file name exactly the same for the file and in the code
- The file is not in the correct location. You use ClassPath method. The file has to be in the classPath. NOT THE WORKING DIRECTORY for instance. It is not the same thing.

  - If you launch your application with `java -jar your.jar` the file need to be in the root directory og the `your.jar` file
  - If you launch with `java -cp a/directory my.Application` the file have to be in he `a/directory` directory.
  - If some resource file is in the `random/directory` you need to launch your application with `java -cp randaom/directory:...other_classpath... your.Application ...`.  Not that `random/direction` can be `.` if it is the same as working directory.

Comment: I added manifest.mf as you can see in my post, hopefully with the correct main class path. I created a jar file and executed it and received: 
$ java -jar target\spring-demo-one-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
        at ttt.springdemo.HelloSpringApp.main(HelloSpringApp.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Comment: As suspected, you set you file in the main directory, not in a directory that is included in your classpath. Move the file or add the directory in your classpath!

Comment: And apparently it is a spring boot application, with a maven build. It means it produce a uber jar. So re-create the `src/main/resources` directory and put it your applicationContext file!  (and Btw, as Spring boot launch itself spring, you should not go this way).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. My mileage with Spring and Spring boot in specifics is exactly 48 hours :) So with boot I understand I don't even need the xml file at all...

Answer (score 0):

Write the correct path

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("packageName/config.xml");
```